# spring-data-neo4j save a list of Users and add relationship by user.id

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Assume that we have a list of Users to be imported into Neo4j database,
and the POJO will be

> User {id:xx, name:xxx, parentId: xxx}

How can we save them, and add relationship at the same time when using spring-data-neo4j, notice that they are in one transaction.
the relationship is based on the user.parentId, and the result will be like:

> User{id:2, name:xxx, parentId: 1}-[r:parent]->User{id:1, name:xxx, parentId: 0}.

And we need to avoid the exception caused by the root User (no parentId for him)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can share your entity-classes so far?

In general there is no need for parent-id's the relationships take care of that for you.

```
@NodeEntity
class User {
  @GraphId Long graphId;

  @Indexed String id;
  String name;
  @RelatedTo(type="parent",direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
  User parent;
}
```

If you want to load the full path to the root eagerly for each user, you might add a @Fetch to the parent field.